# How to list out all the api in an Django application?

Tags: javascript, django

I have an Django application which is around 4 years old.
I want list out all the api in order to remove all inactive api's from the codebase.
Is there any way to figure out all the API?
The application is based on Djnago. We are using javascript for the frontend part.

Comment: this will do the job for you [ https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ]

Comment: checkout this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/

Comment: wow 4 years old code base, what django version do you use? you can check on urls.py first before implement those libraries (DRF & Swagger)

Comment: @taipei we are using Django 1.6